# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int' - either on Controller or on View Page

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

While executing below code, I got this error in my Controller:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Error comes on `t.TOT_QTY` in my controller.

Controller:

```
dcms = (from t in db.ASN_ITEM
                    ...
                    where
                      (t.TOT_QTY - t.SCND_QTY) != 0  
                    select new ASNVarianceRep
                    {                           
                        TOT_QTY = t.TOT_QTY,
                        SCND_QTY = t.SCND_QTY,
                        VAR_QTY = (t.SCND_QTY - t.TOT_QTY)                            
                    }).Distinct();
```

Where `t.TOT_QTY` is of type `int?` in the database. But the variable `TOT_QTY` is just an `int` on Model class.

Model:

```
public class ASNVarianceRep : ASN_ITEM
{  
    public int TOT_QTY { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

If I changed `public int TOT_QTY { get; set; }` to `public Nullable<int> TOT_QTY { get; set; }`, Then error in the controller will be solved. But same error will be there on view page at line `itotqty = itotqty + item.TOT_QTY;`

View:

```
 @if (Model != null)
    {
        var itotqty = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            itotqty = itotqty + item.TOT_QTY;                
        <tr>                
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TOT_QTY)
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        }
        <tr>                
            <td style="text-align: center"><b>@itotqty.ToString() </b></td>                
        </tr>
```

So, what I want is either I need to make the type of `t.TOT_QTY` from `int?` To `int` in Controller or make `var itotqty = 0;` from `int` to `int?` on view page.
How to do so?

Comment: you can use Convert.ToInt(yournullableinteger)  in your, leave your changes in model

Comment: This would be actually Convert.ToInt32(item.yournullableint) in your view. See edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly cast to an `int` in your query when assigning to your model. Currently it is trying to do an implicit cast as failing.

```
dcms = (from t in db.ASN_ITEM
       ...
       where
           (t.TOT_QTY - t.SCND_QTY) != 0  
           select new ASNVarianceRep
           {                           
               TOT_QTY = (int)t.TOT_QTY,
               SCND_QTY = t.SCND_QTY,
               VAR_QTY = (t.SCND_QTY - t.TOT_QTY)                            
           }).Distinct();
```

See this MSDN page for more info on explicit casting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Leave your changes in the model and then in your view

```
 totqty = itotqty + Convert.ToInt32(item.TOT_QTY);
```

Comment: Your int i in ToInt should be in capital case. Sorry for the typo. Just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

`int?` and `int` are basically two different types that you can't implicitly cast to, so you need to do an [explicit cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). Explicit casts look like this:

```
int  myInt  = 3;
byte myByte = (Byte)myInt;
```

Where the `(Byte)` casts the `int` to a `byte`. It does this by create a new variable, preforming a hidden operation, then returning that value, much like a function.

To do that with your example, it would look like this:

```
dcms = (from t in db.ASN_ITEM
   ...
   where
       (t.TOT_QTY - t.SCND_QTY) != 0  
       select new ASNVarianceRep
       {                           
           TOT_QTY = (int)t.TOT_QTY,
           SCND_QTY = t.SCND_QTY,
           VAR_QTY = (t.SCND_QTY - t.TOT_QTY)                            
       }).Distinct();
```

But keep in mind that when you cast from a `Type?` to `Type` there is always a chance of memory loss, in the event you convert a `null` value to an `int`. I'm not sure what what `null` value is cast to, maybe `0`, but point is, you have lost that data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep your model property nullable

```
public Nullable<int> TOT_QTY { get; set; }
```

or

```
public int? TOT_QTY { get; set; }
```

and handle it in your view

```
itotqty = itotqty + (int)(item.TOT_QTY ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert a nullable int to int by the following

```
int temp= t.TOT_QTY ?? default(int);
```